# Diferencia entre input y sys.stdin

Tags: python

A la hora de guardar un dato, sea del tipo que sea, ¿qué ventajas presenta input sobre sys.stdin y/o viceversa?
Por lo que entiendo, el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: ¿Puedes desarrollar un poco más la pregunta? Aunque están relacionadas, no son la misma cosa, ni tienen porqué tener ventajas una sobre la otra.

Comment: Por ejemplo, me refiero en primer lugar al sys.stdin, que permite guardar lo introducido por teclado en una variable, al igual que nos permite hacerlo input. ¿Qué diferencia hay entre ambas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los ***streams* estándares** son `stdin`, `stdout` y `stderr`, y representan *ficheros* conectados con la entrada, salida y salida de errores que tiene por defecto un proceso. Nuestra aplicación no debe asumir nada sobre ellos, ni que la entrada se haga por teclado, ni que la salida vaya a una terminal,...nada, tan sólo que se comportan como ficheros de texto que se leen y/o escriben línea a línea.

La función `input` tiene dos cometidos:

- mostrar un mensaje (en `stdout`)
- leer una línea de texto (de `stdin`)

Este comportamiento se puede simular de la siguiente manera::

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Dame un número:")
sys.stdout.flush()
n = sys.stdin.readline()
```

que equivale a

```
n = input("Dame un número:")
```

Evidentemente, es mucho más cómodo usar `input` que los streams estándares (Lo mismo pasa con usar `print` en lugar de `stdout`). Entonces, ¿para qué sirve usar los streams?.

Como he dicho antes, los streams se pueden ver como ficheros y se pueden intercambiar con ellos donde sea preciso. Es un sistema sencillo de crear baterías de pruebas de fragmentos de código. También es empleado para procesar la salida o entrada de procesos hijos (algo que se sale de tema).

Un ejemplo no trivial:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

class WrapInput:
    def __init__(self, entrada):
        self.entrada = entrada

    def wrapper(self, f, *args, **kw):
        (sys.stdin, old_stdin) = (StringIO(self.entrada), sys.stdin)
        res = f(*args,**kw)
        sys.stdin = old_stdin
        return res

n = WrapInput("2").wrapper(input, "Dame un número: ")   
print("El número es {}".format(n))
```

No espera a que introduzcas el número por teclado, lee el `"2"` almacenado en `StringIO`.

Usar `input` o `stdin` es equivalente. Es más cómodo usar `input` en casi cualquier condición, pero con `stdin` puedes hacer mucha más magia.